# How to use find() from className using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm upgrading some legacy code from JQuery-1.8.3 to JQuery-1.12.4 (too big a jump to latest JQuery). I'm hitting the following issue.

In the code below, I'm adding the "**hidable**" class to #terminal and #text and then inside clearOnSubmit(), I'm trying to select a new value (or setting text with new value) based on the hidable classname. My legacy code is able to do that, but I am having trouble getting that to work.

Basically, I'm trying to get the last two lines highlighted by <<<<<<<<<<<<<.
Thanks for all the helps in advance.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>find demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onClick="runMe()">click me</button>

<div class="span8">

    <select id="terminal">
  
        <option selected='selected' value='blank'></option>
        <option value='test1'>1</option>
        <option value='test2'>2<option>
    </select>
</div>
<input id="text" value="Hello World"/>

<script>  

function runMe() {  
    $('#terminal').val('test1').change();  
    $('#terminal').addClass('hidable');  
    $('#terminal').addClass('valid');  
    $("#text").addClass('hidable');  
    clearOnSubmit();  
  }  
  
  function clearOnSubmit() {
    $('.hidable').css("color", "green");  
    
    $("input").val('Hi THERE').change();  
    
   $('.hidable').find("select").val('test2').change();  // <<<<<<<<<<
    $('.hidable').find("input").css("color", "blue");    // <<<<<<<<<<
  }
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
}
```

Comment: Nothing there to [**find**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) .. you already added `hidable` class to the same element which you want to work with .. `$('select#terminal.hidable').val('test2').change();` And `$('input#text.hidable').css("color", "blue");`

Comment: Don't see how this would work in any version since `find()` looks for descendants. That means you are looking for inputs inside inputs ( or select)

Comment: Also there should be no difference between 1.8 and 1.12 for anything you are using. Most of those methods have been essentially the same for years

Comment: Glad to know there are no difference. What I don't understand was this two lines of code:
  
$('.hidable').find($("input")).val('');  
$('.hidable').find($("select")).val('blank').change()  
  

Used in 1.8.3. With 1.12.4, after returning from the function with the above two lines, the checking for blank:

Assert.areEqual('blank', $('#terminal').val(), '#terminal'));  

started failing. With 1.8.3, $('#terminal').val() is 'blank' but with 1.12.4, it is null.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure exactly what you want. But if I am right then following code might work.

Use

```
$('.hidable').val('test2').change();
    if($("#text").hasClass('hidable')) {
      $("#text").css("color", "blue");
    }
```

Instead of using

```
$('.hidable').find("select").val('test2').change();  // <<<<<<<<<<
$('.hidable').find("input").css("color", "blue");    // <<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: Simpler than hasClass conditional is just `$("#text.hidable").css("color", "blue")`

Comment: Yes. It will be simpler :)

Comment: Yes, this:


`$('select#terminal.hidable').val('test2').change();
$('input#text.hidable').css("color", "blue");`

worked!